# MySQL Inserting into locked aliased table

Tags: mysql, insert, locking

I am trying to insert data into a InnoDB MySQL table which is locked using an alias and I cannot for the life of me get it to work!

The following works:

```
LOCK TABLES Problems p1 WRITE, Problems p2 WRITE, Server READ;
SELECT * FROM Problems p1;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

But try and do an insert and it doesn't work (it claims there is a syntax error round the 'p1' in my INSERT):

```
LOCK TABLES Problems p1 WRITE, Problems p2 WRITE, Server READ;
INSERT INTO Problems p1 (SomeCol) VALUES(43534);
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Help please!

Comment: It looks like you are trying to redefine the alias inside the INSERT command. When you reference an aliased table, just use the alias name. I don't know whether or not you can actually use an alias for an INSERT, but try this for the INSERT: `INSERT INTO p1 (SomeCol) VALUES(43534);`

Answer (score 2):

Just lock both the aliased and the non-aliased table
es: LOCK TABLES Problems WRITE, Problems p1 WRITE, Problems p2 WRITE, Server READ;

Answer (score 0):

Use INSERT INTO Problems (SomeCol) VALUES(43534);
No p1...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have already tried this. Due to the fact that the lock is done with an alias (which I need to do) and INSERT doesn't reference the alias at all you get an error 'Table 'Problems' was not locked with LOCK TABLES'

Answer (score 0):

just faced the same problem, unfortunately `INSERT INTO table_name [AS alias] VALUES ...` is not supported in mysql